# sys.system_internals_partition_columns view on Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

The sys.system_internals_partition_columns view on Azure SQL doesn't seem to exist. Is there another view I can use to examine index modifications on a per column basis against an Azure SQL DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to grab out of the referenced system view. Much of the data you care about is likely still exposed to you, but through the Database related DMVs which have more or less been around in some fashion since SQL Server 2005 with additions in versions since.

You might have some luck with querying a few of these DMVs. You can explore with `SELECT * FROM`

- `sys.dm_db_partition_stats`
- `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)` (specifying the parameters required for your usage)
- `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`

etc.

There are quite a few database level and connection information level Dynamic Management Views exposed to you in Azure SQL DB.